# \tkzSetUpLine doesn't seem to affect \tkzDrawCircle

Tags: tkz-euclide

At page 193 of tkz-euclide documentation, we see some options to tweak "styles" in the preamble. However, none of the options seem to have any effect on line width of \tkzDrawCircle. I thought either the Line or the Arc variation of the command would work. Am I misunderstanding how it works? If that's not supposed to work this way at all, how can I set up a line style for \tkzDrawCircle?

```
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage{tkz-euclide}
\tkzSetUpLine[line width=.8pt]

\begin{document}

    \begin{tikzpicture}
    \tkzDefPoints{0/0/A, 1/0/B}
    \tkzDrawCircle(A, B)
    \end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to tex.sx.

Comment: You need to use `\tkzSetUpCircle[line width=0.8pt]`

Comment: Welcome to tex.sx ! You can use `\tkzSetUpCircle` but it's not documented (I think??) . Personally, I prefer to use my own style like `tikzset{new/.style={color=orange,line width=.2pt}} `.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Update : if you want to use the same style for lines and circles:

```
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage{tkz-euclide}
\tkzSetUpLine[color=orange,thick]
\tikzset{circle style/.style     = {line style}}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
    \tkzDefPoints{0/0/A, 1/0/B}
    \tkzDrawCircle(A, B)
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Since the latest versions, the solution is `\tkzSetUpCircle`. The problem is that it's not yet in the documentation. It's in the `tkz-euclide.cfg` file. This is my fault, because I often don't use it, as in the following example with "new". Before the introduction of `tkzSetUpCircle`, you had to use `tkzSetUpLine`.

```
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage{tkz-euclide}
\tkzSetUpCircle[ultra thick]
\tikzset{new/.style={color=orange,line width=8pt}}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
    \tkzDefPoints{0/0/A, 1/0/B}
    \tkzDrawCircle(A, B)
    \end{tikzpicture}

    \begin{tikzpicture}
    \tkzDefPoints{0/0/A, 1/0/B}
    \tkzDrawCircle[new](A, B)
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Hi! I'm the one who submitted the typos yesterday, but I didn't want to bother you with this simple question. Thank you, it works. I'm still having trouble reproducing some details from the 5yo document I have. Seems like many default options have changed in the meantime, though that's to be expected. One that I've figured out immediately was below vs below right for \tkzLabelPoints, but some are a bit trickier. I'll keep working on it. Thank you again!

Answer (score 3):

The command `\tkzSetUpLine` works in and outside the preamble, as illustrated below. The line width can also be specified as an option to the command `\tkzDrawCircle`.

[image]

```
\documentclass[border=6pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tkz-euclide}
\tkzSetUpLine[line width=.8pt]
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\tkzDefPoints{0/0/A,1/0/B}
\tkzDrawCircle(A,B)
\end{tikzpicture}%
\tkzSetUpLine[line width=8pt]%
\begin{tikzpicture}
\tkzDefPoints{0/0/A,1/0/B}
\tkzDrawCircle(A,B)
\end{tikzpicture}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\tkzDefPoints{0/0/A,1/0/B}
\tkzDrawCircle[line width=3pt](A,B)
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: What's your version of tkz-euclide? I think it's no longer possible on the latest version.

Comment: @AlainMatthes This was compiled with version 2022/01/19 4.03 of tkz-euclide. As you mentioned, it indeed does not work with version 2023/10/26 5.04c.